# Width and height of every element is shown 100% in photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, measurement

I want to know the width and height of a rectangle in a Photoshop CS6 design. When I select it's layer and press `Ctrl + T` it's width and height both are mentioned 100%. The problem is with every other layer. Whichever layer I select the width and height are always 100%.

So, how do I check the width and height of an element in pixels?

Comment: Select the layer pixels (ctrl click on layer) and look in the info panel?

Comment: @joojaa Width and height are shown blank in the info panel.

Comment: Then no pixels are selected

Comment: @joojaa So how to do select pixels of that layer?

Comment: ctrl+ click on layer icon

Comment: I have done `ctrl + click` on layer too but still width and height are shown blank.

Comment: right click the 100% and change the units

Answer (score 2):

Right Click the value to change the units:

[image: Change units]

Comment: Can this be set to default in someway? Every time I select a new layer I have to manually change the units.

Comment: I don't think so, no.